# how to put react tic tac toe in ant design header sider layout?

Tags: reactjs

I have finished the tic tac toe guide. Now I wanted to experiment with ant design, but something seems to be wrong. I took the code from and design and I tried to put the  tag in the jsx code. I am getting error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

All I did by far was change the root div in HTML to container div. Both the tic tac toe game code and the layout code work fine separately. but once I try to put the  tag in layout content page, I get the error mentioned above.

**Layout code** - [link to source.](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6mjj18v24)

**Game code.**(just the game part, the squares and board is excluded) - [link to source.](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010)

**the problem appears when I put  tag in the code above.**

```
     <Content style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 24, margin: 0, minHeight: 280 }}>
        <Game />
     </Content>
```

**The layout works fine without the Game tag and the Game works fine when used just in ReactDOM.render.**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

**Why is  tag not working? How do I make it work?**

**I figured it out.** I copied the game code in layout codesandbox source and it worked. than I copied the same code in my project and it worked there too. I took both codes and compared them and the only difference was in order of ReactDOM.render and Game.component. As shown in below answer the code works fine when copied correctly.

- **lesson 1: ReactDOM.render should come after the component code.**
- **lesson 2: keep big codes in different files.**

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible sample of your problem.

Comment: I am not sure what would be minimal, reproducible sample for this code. but I could pinpoint where the problem is. I could leave only those parts of the code in here and leave the rest in the source. to reproduce my code you should just copy first code that I provided into tic tac toe app in react tutorial and change div id in html to "container" instead of "root".

Comment: It's not my job to copy stuff around. It's yours. And then remove all code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem. That will then be the minimal, reproducible sample

Comment: 1. Paste the game code into the layout code. 2. Ensure the error occurs 3. Remove some code from the game. 4. Ensure the error occurs. 5. Remove some more code from the game 6. Rinse and repeat until the error no longer appears -> Revert last remove -> That's your minimum sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's work fine!!

i copy and paste your codes to a single CodeSandBox and it's work currectly
look at this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5k6workkvl

Comment: Yea I just did the same and it did work. I am trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: The problem was in the order. I didn't realize that mattered.